# How to get a list with all possible assignments for workers?

Tags: python, vb.net

I've got the following problem:
I have N workers. Each of them can be assigned to one of 4 tasks T1, T2, T3 and T4. I would like to generate a list with all the assignment possibilities like this:

```
W1->T1, W2->T1, ... Wx->T1  
W1->T1, W2->T1, ... Wx->T2  
W1->T1, W2->T2, ... Wx->T2  
...  
W1->T4, W2->T4, ... Wx->T4
```

How can I do this? Python or VB.NET code would be the best, but any language will do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You can then come back as soon as you have tried to solve the problem yourself and we will be happy to help if you have a specific problem with *your implementation*.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove SO has shortcuts for the common links Ask, Tour, MCVE and Help.  Just wrap them in square brackets `[` + `Tour` + `]`

Comment: @Plutonix Hey thanks for that. Will go back and read the help under a cloud of irony ;)

Comment: @NiallCosgrove I do not think they are documented anywhere, but they are mentioned on meta

Comment: Found them thanks. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments  has the full list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import itertools

def show_assignments(workers, tasks):
    prod = itertools.product(*[range(tasks)]*workers)
    for a in prod:
        print(", ".join("W%d->T%d" % (w+1, t+1) for (w, t) in enumerate(a)))
```

You can call it, for instance, as:

```
show_assignments(5, 4)
```

This will display the results as:

```
W1->T1, W2->T1, W3->T1, W4->T1, W5->T1
W1->T1, W2->T1, W3->T1, W4->T1, W5->T2
...
W1->T4, W2->T4, W3->T4, W4->T4, W5->T3
W1->T4, W2->T4, W3->T4, W4->T4, W5->T4
```

Comment: It seems usable, I like it, but I don't know if I understand it right. Could you give me an example where I've got 6 workers and 4 tasks, so I can understand what is what?

Comment: Ok, I updated it to produce the specific result you were looking for.  The example I gave has 5 workers and 4 tasks.

Comment: I assume that's what you were looking for.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yup, that's it! I've wrote that code for 5 workers and 4 tasks and it produced exactly what I've expected - 1024 rows of unique assignment possibilities. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code better. But for an example this will work (python 3.6)

```
workers = ["W1","W2","W3","W4","W5"] #workers
tasks = ["T1","T2","T3","T4"] #tasks
for worker in workers:
    for task in tasks:
        print(worker + " >> " + task)
```

Comment: If I understand it right, it will generate something like a list of all workers with all assignments, but not a combination of worker assignment with other workers assignments. Am I right? If yes, then it's not an answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the pool of workers and the pool of tasks.

There's a standard function for this: 
[python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
[python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

So perhaps you need `itertools.product(workers, tasks)`?

Comment: According to documentation: product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy. I need a list of all combinations of assignments not only a list of any worker to any assignment. It won't produce output I need.